# On edit trigger - when "x" is typed in and when "x" is deleted in cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I created a piece of code to a sheet where people mark "x" if they can't make it to training. It is made in google sheets, and   It makes a timestamp when they hit "x".

**What i need is an onedit trigger, that activated when "x" is typed and when "x" i deleted in a cell.**

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (sheet.getName() ==
"Mandagstræning","Tirsdagstræning","Torsdagstræning","Holdkamp") {
var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, editColumn, 1,
sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Tid") + editColumn;
if (sheet.getRange(rowIndex, orderCol).getValue() === "x") {
sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new
Date(), "UTC+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"));
}
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Sorry. Yes it is in google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet, watchCol, dateCol, sheetInd;
sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
watchCol = 2;
dateCol = 6;
sheetInd = ["Mandagstræning", "Tirsdagstræning", "Torsdagstræning", "Holdkamp"].indexOf(sheet.getName());
if (sheetInd > -1 && e.range.columnStart === watchCol && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, dateCol).setValue(e.value == 'x' ? Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss") : null);
}
}
```

Change the var watchCol and dateCol to match your requirements. This example script will put a timestamp in column 6 (dateCol), when an 'x' is entered  in column 2 (watchCol), but only in the aforementioned sheets. I hope that helps?

Comment: I also need it to make an timestamp when "x" is removed from column 2.

Comment: You can see an example off my sheet here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CW7TxvwW_ewFUheioPAxXAlkVKE6n0Lt5vPvi_V4dvc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Where do you want the timestamp to appear? I can't see a value "Tid" in the header row?